# JNLP file services denied access to local files

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start, jnlp, fileopendialog

I am trying to write a small java applet to read user browsing history. Thus all I need to do is to read files on the user's local filesystem.

I haven't succeeded in it though. When I try to use JNLP API's ExtendedService openFile(), the getInputStream() fails with an IOException. I tried to use the FileOpenService openFileDialog(), but when the dialog opens, directories appear either empty, or with a non-accessible icon.

Screenprints here : http://timewitnesser.com/publisher/screenshot1.png and here http://timewitnesser.com/publisher/screenshot2.png

Some details on how I built and deployed it : I basically followed Java applet's deployment guidelines here : docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html

- I used a jnlp file to launch the applet. I tried both with security set to all-permissions or not specified. Here's the code of jnlp file :

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
      <information>
          <title>History Reader</title>
          <vendor>QualityWeb</vendor>
      </information>
      <resources>
          <j2se version="1.7+"
              href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
          <jar href="HistoryReaderApplet.jar" main="true" />
      </resources>
      <security>
          <all-permissions/>
      </security>
      <applet-desc 
           name="History Reader Applet"
           main-class="historyreaderapplet.HistoryReaderApplet"
           width="300"
           height="300">
       </applet-desc>
       <update check="background"/>
  </jnlp>
  ```
- In my html page, I launch it with this code :

  ```
  <script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
  <script> 
  var attributes = {
     code:'historyreaderapplet.HistoryReaderApplet',  width:300, height:300} ; 
  var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'historyreader_applet.jnlp'} ; 
  deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.7');
  </script>
  ```
- I build the jar using the jar command, including a manifest in which I specify the 3 lines mentioned in the java guidelines, including the "Permission one". The command I use is `jar cvfm HistoryReaderApplet.jar mymanifest.txt historyreaderapplet`
- I sign the jar using jarsigner, although I have generated my keys myself with keytool, I don't have a certificate signed by a certificate authority
- I have even tried to set my local java machine security settings to medium and I have added my domain to the list of trusted domains.
- I have tried both running the page from a local server, and uploading to a remote server
- When I run the page, it prompts with an authorization box, where I allow the app. When I run in sandbox mode, when it reaches the fileopendialog thing, it prompts me again for whether I want to authorize the app to read and write on local file system, which I do. But then even with all these confirmations, it doesn't work.

Any idea what could be the problem?

EDIT : Here is the report from Janela, I included only the red parts :

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'security'. One of '{resources, application-desc, applet-desc, component-desc, installer-desc}' is expected.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'security'. One of '{resources, application-desc, applet-desc, component-desc, installer-desc}' is expected.
Codebase '' is a malformed URL!  Defaulting to http://timewitnesser.com/publisher/historyreader_applet.jnlp
Codebase '' is a malformed URL!  Defaulting to http://timewitnesser.com/publisher/historyreader_applet.jnlp
Codebase '' is a malformed URL!  Defaulting to http://timewitnesser.com/publisher/historyreader_applet.jnlp
Codebase '' is a malformed URL!  Defaulting to http://timewitnesser.com/publisher/historyreader_applet.jnlp
```

It seems to me that the first lines could be the reason, but I don't understand them. Isn't the "security" tag supposed to be direct child of the jnlp tag ?

Comment: With `<all-permissions/>` it should be possible to bypass the JNLP API file services and use the methods of the `File` API along with `JFileChooser` etc.  I suspect that path might be more productive.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried using just the File API, but then I get an IOException : _/Users/vic/Documents/Moul.rtf (Operation not permitted)_. I have the `<all-permissions/>` tag in the security tag, my manifest also includes it. What could be wrong ?

Comment: I tried the same with adding `AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {…});`, still same error...

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: What version of Java are you running?  Any chance you are hitting the new security updates from Java7?  Self-signed certificates are not allowed, unless you lower the 'Security Level' to medium in the Java Control Panel (windows).

Comment: @mikemil, I am running Java 7 indeed. However, even when I set the security level to medium, I still get the exact same error. In order to try though, any idea how I might get a certificate for testing purposes without having to spend too much ?

Comment: I just edited my question with the jnlp report

Comment: JaNeLA is reporting a problem with the *order* of the elements.  It is not that the `security` element should not be included, but that it should be included earlier in the file!

Comment: Interesting. So right now it is after information and resources. Should I put it first ?

Comment: I tried changing the order to put the security element first or after information, I still get the same problem. Although now Janela doesn't bring up the issue anymore

Comment: You need to find the DTD or schema that defined the JNLP format/syntax and that will tell you what the order should be.  Our files have information, then security and then resources, if that helps.

Comment: Ok thanks. Indeed Janela seemed to validate security in second position, but I still get the same problem while executing the file